# Compress image php with move_uploaded_files

Tags: php, image, compression

I have a php script which upload a photo from an Ajax call, and i want to upload the photo two times, one with standard size and another one compressed. Does anyone know how to do it with this following code? I tried to compress the image with scripts that I found on stackoverflow, but I can't do it correctly. Everytime appears an black photo.

I got this code:

```
$data = array();
if (isset($_GET['files'])) {
    $error = false;
    $files = array();
    $uniqid = uniqid();
    $uploaddir = '../../images/'.$uniqid;
    foreach($_FILES as $file) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.basename($file['name']))) {
            $files[] = $uploaddir.$file['name'];
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' = > 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' = > $files);
} else {
    $arr - > image = $file['name'];
    $_SESSION['image'] = "img-".$file['name'];
    $arr - > ok = "ok";
    $data = array('success' = > 'Form was submitted', 'formData' = > $file['name']);
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You use `basename()` on `move_uploaded_file()` but not when you store it in your `$files` array: `$files[] = $uploaddir.basename($file['name']);`

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` can only move an uploaded file to its final location. You can't modify a file with this function.

Comment: You can check this link https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-reduce-image-file-size-while-uploading-using-php-code/

Answer (score 0):

Try using basename() also in your $files[] array insertion:

Change this:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.basename($file['name']))) {
            $files[] = $uploaddir.$file['name'];
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.basename($file['name']))) {
            $files[] = $uploaddir.basename($file['name']);
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
```